# Default argument to represent "do all"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'd like to give the run method a default argument so that it will run all test cases if no test_cases argument is given. How would you recommend I do this?

```
from collections import OrderedDict
class TestCase(OrderedDict):
    def run(self, test_cases):
        for test_case_name in test_cases:
            self[test_case_name].run()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
class TestCase(OrderedDict):
    def run(self, test_cases=None):
        if test_cases is None:
            test_cases = default_all_test_cases # add all your default test cases here
        for test_case in test_cases:
            test_case.run()
```

You can replace the default `None` by another **immutable** object, such as string or integer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `test_cases=None`, then just say `if not test_cases: test_cases=[all,values,here]`; such condition will work for empty sequences as well.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking along the same lines but it is a little funny having None to represent all I thought...

Comment: It is a common idiom really. Think of `None` as "unspecified" rather than nothing. If someone wanted to run no tests, he/she would not call the method in the first place.

Comment: `None` is unspecified, and is very commonly used to specify a 'default'.  It makes sense that if `test_cases` is specified by the caller, it will be a list, possibly of size 0.  eumiro is correct that the default must be **immutable**, as specifying a default of `[]` instead of `None` in the function definition will cause problems.